# How to return message Not Matched Excel when are Identical return false?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular-cli, asp.net-core-webapi, angular-components

I make web api return message `Not Matched Excel` when flag areIdentical is false
and when flag areIdentical is true return file

What I have Tried

```
web api
[Route("ExportNxp")]
        public IActionResult ExportNxp(bool areIdentical)
        {
         
                if (areIdentical == false)
                {
                    return OK("Not Matched Excel");
                }
                else  
                {
                   
                return PhysicalFile(zipPath, "application/zip", Path.GetFileName(zipPath));
              
                }

        }
service.ts
PostUploadzipNxp(file:any):Observable<any>
{
  formData.append('file', file,file.name);
  return this.http.post('http://localhost:61265/api/Z2Delivery/ExportNxp/', formData,{observe: 'response', responseType: 'blob' });
}
component.ts
 this._dataService.PostUploadzipNxp(this.fileToUpload)
     .subscribe(blob => {
       saveAs(blob.body, this.fileToUpload?.name +'.zip');
      });
```

Result I need

```
if (areIdentical == false)
{
display message "Not Matched Excel" on angular component 
}
```

Comment: update and modify i need will be on angular component so are there are any thing not clear

Comment: can any one help me